# Find p such that a quadratic congruence has solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^2 \equiv 5 (mod$ $p)$

How can we find p such that the congruence above has solutions?

We know $x^2 \equiv 5 (mod$ $p)$ has solutions iff $5^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 (mod$ $p)$. Does this help to solve the question?

Comment: You just want one?   note that $6^2=36\equiv 5\pmod {31}$ so $p=31$ works.  If you want to classify all such $p$, use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity law answers the question, but this theorem is far from trivial. You need it, sort of.

Comment: @lulu Well, I prefer to take a look at quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Sure, but then $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4\implies \left( \frac 5p\right)=\left( \frac p5 \right)$ so (for odd $p$ at least) we just want $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$ since those are the squares $\pmod 5$. Direct application of quadratic reciprocity.  Granted, that this result is fairly deep.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your notation but $7^2\equiv 5(mod 22)$ and $5^{(22-1)/2}$ isn't integer at all

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov  I assume the OP intended for $p$ to be an odd prime.  I agree that this is not specified in the post, but if something else is intended it should really be specified.

Comment: @lulu Ok, I'm not much in this, don't know what is assumed or not. Thanks

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov  Oh, your instincts are correct...you should always specify clearly what variables mean.  Here...well, using $p$ to denote a prime is ubiquitous in number theory, and it's not unusual to see people use it that way without being explicit.  Again, I might have it wrong...the OP really ought to settle the point.

Comment: @lulu I still don't understand the question, he offers a statement that seems as an answer, is that statement correct or not? Obviously I'm out of the subject...

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov  It is a standard question, in number theory, to ask "given an integer $a$, find all primes $p$ for which $x^2\equiv a \pmod p$ has a solution.  Fermat showed that this was equivalent to finding $p$ for which $x^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod p$.  This is not terribly difficult, but it was the first big result of this type.  Of course, this doesn't really tell you the list of primes.  If you look at an earlier comment of mine I use a much deeper theorem (due to Gauss) to show that the list is "all primes of the form $5n\pm 1$".

Comment: @lulu can you explain in more detail for your second comment? I lost after the first step. Isn't $5 \equiv 1 (mod 4)$ enough for applying the law of quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Well, knowing that $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that we can "flip" the Legendre symbol without changing the sign.  You still have to solve $\left( \frac p5 \right) = 1$.  To do that, we remark that the only non-zero squares $\pmod 5$ are $\pm 1$, so we need $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$.  As a check, $p=11$ works, as $4^2\equiv 5 \pmod {11}$  but $p=17$ does not work, as we can see by simply checking for solutions.